# Is there an Eclipse RCP Calendar Widget I can add objects to?

Tags: calendar, eclipse-rcp, widget

I'm writing an Eclipse RCP app and want to add a calendar widget showing things happening each day (like the calendar on an Android phone).

I've seen the Nebula DateChooser, but this seems more for choosing a date than static display of information.

Features I would like:
 - Ability to add items to the calendar and the date to be highlighted
 - Being able to colour code the entries would be cool.
 - Being able to click on a date and it to show details of what is scheduled when during the day (e.g. in another view - like an Outlook calendar)

Thanks

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

The only one I can find out there would be the [JaretCalendar](http://xpmp.de/jaretcalendar.html), but is still somewhat a "work in progress".

[image]

The [CalypsoRPC Calendar](http://calypsorcp.sourceforge.net/screenshots.php#caly) is like a Proof of Concept.

[image]

Comment: Thanks VonC they look the sort of thing.  I'll have a look into them